# Changing plugin locale at runtime in Cakephp 3

Tags: cakephp, internationalization, cakephp-3.0

I'm trying to change locale in the plugin that is used as a theme.In my AppController I set the locale with:

> I18n::locale('bs');

And in the plugin that is named 'Admin' I place the translation file in this location:

```
Admin  
/src  
   /Locale  
        /bs  
           admin.po
```

Locale does seem to change, but it doesn't fetch the translations from the translation file. What could be the problem?

Comment: Well, are you actually using the `admin` domain in any of your `__d*()` calls?

Comment: No,that was it. Didn't figure out I have to use domain calls, thx.

Comment: You're welcome... you may want to add that as a quick answer and accept it later on so that the question appears solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I wasn't using domain name while translating strings. You need to use __d() with the name of your plugin as the domain.